# Pfsense - blocking a ping immediately

Tags: ping, pfsense

I am having a issue with pfsense...

I have a rule that block ping (echo requests) from the LAN network interface to a openvpn client interface (OVP1), the rule is working fine blocking the ping to the prohibited network...

For example if i start a ping in a machine to the prohibited network it is giving:

```
Timed out.
Timed out.
Timed out.
```

When i disabled the rule, obviously:

```
Answer from...
Answer from...
Answer from...
```

What i think is perfect correctly.

But then when i re-enable the block rule, the ping don't stops, except if i stop the ping on the machine before changing the rule - i tried to wait some minutes thinking pfsense was needing to reload the rules but the ping are still running. So what i am watching is that is impossible to stop a ping that is already running, even if i block all the firewall traffic in all interfaces, what i think is very unexpected for me that are using until now other firewalls like Iptables, Endian, or Cisco ASA FW - other protocols seems to do not have this issue.

I am creating the rule, as a floating rule and marking "Apply the action immediately on match.". I tried to create it in the LAN tab too but the effect was exactly the same.

On Endian FW for example i am able to stop the ping immediatily if the rule is re-enabled.

What is wrong with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer on the pfsense forum :

Established states are not affected by rule changes. Kill them first via **Diagnostics -> States**.

https://forum.netgate.com/topic/137097/how-to-block-a-running-ping/2

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Right, i will do it.